# Embedded YouTube videos are missing Full screen functionality

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

If I view videos on YouTube I see the Full screen button, as well as being able to double-click the video. If a YouTube video is embedded on a non-YouTube site however, I'm missing both the button and the double-click short cut. Double click simply pauses/unpauses.

This is using latest stable Chrome on Windows when logged in. If I run an incognito tab so I'm logged out, the Full screen button appears again.Logged in using Chrome on OSX does acts as expected. I'm using the same extensions on both OSX/Windows. Disabling all extensions has no effect.

Some examples:

- http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2013/03/27/make-it-to-break-it-planetary-annihilations-creation-tech/
- http://www.theverge.com/2013/3/27/4099100/income-at-home-herbalife-scamworld-biz-opp

and a screenshot:

[image: a screenshot]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's intentional on YouTubes part (for whatever reason). It's the same way for me.

Comment: I think you're right, however why I only get it on Windows and not OSX boggles my brain.

Comment: Okey dokey, added 2 examples. I've not foung a single non-youtube site however that lets me fullscreen in that browser.

Comment: @DanH: That is actually very interesting, yeah.

Comment: Interestingly, while I am aware of this problem myself, the two links you posted above *have* a fullscreen button on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is now fixed. I think it's probably a Youtube update as I haven't restarted Chrome as far as I can remember for maybe a week but I'm sure I've seen the problem within that time.

Answer (score 0):

Someone recently introduced me to the Chrome extension [SmartVideo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smartvideo-for-youtube/lnkdbjbjpnpjeciipoaflmpcddinpjjp).

The extension has an option to enable the fullscreen support if it isn't provided:

[image]

Comment: Infact the problem has come back after maybe a day of not seeing it. Thanks very much I'll give this a go :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case :(

Comment: To elaborate, a number of the settings have no effects, for instance at http://www.theverge.com/2013/4/27/4275736/magnetic-field-visualization-carsten-nicolai. The auto play/buffer settings do nothing as well. However the Loop all videos and Hide player settings popups do work, so the extension is clearly being loaded and doing something.